# How to dynamically assign a property in a collection 

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I work on C#.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean( item.Cells[0].Value) == true)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            **class oclass=new class();
            oclass.property = item.Cells[col.Name].Value.ToString();
            Collection.add(oclass);**
        }
    }

}
```

In the above **syntax**,i want to fill class **property dynamically**.I also add my class in **collection**.Is it possible in C#,fill class property dynamically?My grid contain more than one column.My grid's column name are same as class property name.**I want to do the bellow thing:**

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    **class oclass=new class();
    oclass.col.Name= item.Cells[col.Name].Value.ToString();
    Collection.add(oclass);**
}
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do this with `PropertyInfo.SetValue()`.**

Within the example, I've added an explanation of what it all does.

I've used the class `TestClass` for this example. First I get the type.

```
var type = typeof(TestClass);
```

Then, I build a dictionary of all column names and a `PropertyInfo` which is a reference to the property of the class with the same name as the column.

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    properties.Add(col.Name, type.GetProperty(col.Name));
}
```

Then, for each row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean( item.Cells[0].Value) == true)
    {
```

I create a new instance of `TestClass`.

```
        var instance = new TestClass();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
```

I take the property from the dictionary and use the method `SetValue` to set the value of the instance with the value from the column. But, to be able to do this, we must first ensure that the type is correct.

```
            object value = Convert.ChangeType(item.Cells[col.Name].Value, properties[col.Name].PropertyType);

            properties[col.Name].SetValue(instance, value, null);
        }
```

And last, I add the instance to the collection.

```
        Collection.Add(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: this line :properties.Add(type.GetProperty(col.Name);-----"Error 1 No overload for method 'Add' takes '1' arguments"show the error message.

Comment: Above process works when my  class properties are string type, my properties are various types like int,string,double,datetime.If i want to fill those properties by using the above technique,show me error"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".What to do.

Comment: Updated answer to automatically convert the value to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

i miss the sense of your question, what do you want to achieve with the second snippet ? Btw yes, you can set the value of a class member(property) at runtime if that property is already defined in the class. Alternatives are to derive a new class from the parent one and add the missing members or if you want something more dynamic well use the dynamic type introduced with .Net 4.